# Yii Model behavior integer to boolean

Tags: model, yii, yii-behaviour

I have model class like this

```
/**
 * @property integer $is_active
 */
class User extends CActiveRecord {
....
}

$User = User::model()->findByPk(1);
```

In mysql `is_active` is always return `1` or `0`, i want whenever i call `$User->is_active`.
It will output `boolean` not `integer`.
How to do that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Change your field to a TinyInt and yii will handle it accordingly